# Why laravel vue js this.form.post(url) automatically converting into get method

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Vue.js get method is working instead of post method.
but in localhost its working perfectly.
Only facing this issue when i'm upload project into server

```
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            form: new Form({
                company_name : '',
                address : '',
                contact_name : '',
                number : '',
                keyword_or_comment : '',
                attachment : ''
            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createPhoneBook(){
            this.$Progress.start();
            const url = `${API_URL}/api/apiurl/`;
            this.form.post(url)
            .then(() => {
                toast.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Phone book added successfully'
                })
                this.$Progress.finish();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.$Progress.fail()
            })
        }
    },
    created() {
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me,
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you show your code

Comment: now i pasted my code also

Comment: Check your network panel  - I'd bet you're getting a 301/302 redirect. Perhaps a HTTPS redirect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use axios Ajax request. this is highly recommended for vue js.

like:

```
axios.post(location.pathname, { body: this.body })
            .catch(error => {
                flash(error.response.data, "danger");
            })
            .then(({ data }) => {
                this.body = "";

            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your respons.
I get it fixed. The issue is in my url,
my url had a '/' at the end.
When i remove it the post method is working...